# Container of type size with children height

Tags: css, containers, media-queries

My situation is the following: I'd like to apply some styling to a div when its overflow's (Y axis) scroll-bar is visible.
I'd like to avoid using JavaScript and, instead, using a CSS only solution.

I bumped into container queries.

The problem is the following.
When I try to set the **container-type** to **size** (since I need to perform a @container query with a min-height value), the container requires to specify an height.

Is it possible to set its height to the children's one?

The code can be simplified in this way:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="children">
      // content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where the styling is:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
}
.container {
  container: name / size(?);
}
.children{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

And the @container query I'd like to write is something like:

```
@container name (min-height: 301px){
  .children{
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
}
```

Aka,  when the overflow scroll bar is visible, add a margin to the children.
And, for archieving that, the container must not have the height of the parent (limited to 300px) but, instead the one of the children (n px where n could be bigger than 300px).

I tried to look around but I've found nothing.

(I'd prefer to know if it's possible via @container queries but, if it's not possible, I'll appreciate any other kind of answer **CSS only** or a "it's not possible without JS" one)

Thanks :)